# Best Practice for encoding architecture in maven artifact?

Tags: maven

What is the best place to put platform/architecture info?

My temptation is to use the version field by prefixing the architecture designator to the version, since that would appear to be the simplest to wildcard and also will prevent accidentally mixing and matching of different platforms:

```
version = <architecture>-<version>[-<branch>]
```

Alternatively, one could append the architecture to the artifact id:

```
artifactId = <name>-<architecture>
```

Both ways lead to the same artifact name.

What do other people do, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing for different architectures independently, any of these solutions may be good. You may have a situation, though, where the version number would be the same across architectures. This may typically be the case if you're building for the different architectures off of the same code base, e.g. either you have an artifact that is built into different distributables, or you have different artifacts that depend on the same common core. In that case, you would not want to pollute the version number with the architecture or branch information, as it renders Maven unable to treat it as the same version. The proposed solution for this is the use of **classifiers**. As per the [Maven POM Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies):

> **classifier**:
>   The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were
>   built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some
>   optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the
>   artifact name just after the version number.
>
> As a motivation for this element, consider for example a project that
>   offers an artifact targeting JRE 1.5 but at the same time also an
>   artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be
>   equipped with the classifier `jdk15` and the second one with `jdk14` such
>   that clients can choose which one to use.

Comment: One problem with using architecture as classifier is that the packaging and the dependencies might differ between architectures. I see you carefully mention "built from the same POM", but that is generally not the case. It would be _nice_ if one could merge POMs, but I fear we'll have to encode architecture into the version.

Comment: Using different classifiers does not preclude you from using different types (to account for differences in packaging). I agree that the differences in dependencies, may, however, be a breaking point here, not so much in use of `classifier`, but rather in "building from the same POM", as you observe.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the publish ant task wrong, but my observation was that if I use classifiers and different packaging types, the last upload "wins" and declares the packaging type for the whole set, which effectively renders the architectures using a different packaging type inaccessible via maven'y methods (if you know the url or build the url yourself, you can still get them, but the POM will not show them).